# Try and Catch statement for words

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I would like to use a try and catch statement for if anyone inputs something other than a word. In my previous experience, if there is no error, it is hard to use it. If someone inputs a number for example, their first name, their is no error. Is there anyway I can use a try and catch statement?

```
try {
    String firstName, middleInitial, lastName, Firstname;
    char firstNameCase, middleInitialCase, lastNameCase;

    firstName = firstNameInput.getText();
    middleInitial = middleInitialInput.getText();
    lastName = lastNameInput.getText();

    char firstNameLetter = firstName.charAt(0);
    firstNameCase = Character.toLowerCase(firstNameLetter);

    char lastNameLetter = lastName.charAt(0);
    lastNameCase = Character.toUpperCase(lastNameLetter);

    char middleInitialLetter = middleInitial.charAt(0);
    middleInitialCase = Character.toLowerCase(middleInitialLetter);

    String firstNameFinal = Character.toString(firstNameCase);
    String lastNameFinal = Character.toString(lastNameCase);
    String middleInitialFinal = Character.toString(middleInitialCase);

    String monogram = firstNameFinal+lastNameFinal + middleInitialFinal;

    monogramOutput.setText("Your monogram is: " + monogram); 
} catch(I dont know what to put here) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "One or more fields contains invalid data","Error Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: You can explicitly check if it is a number but how are you going to know if it is a "word".

Comment: Well given that a name *is* a word, it will be difficult to check for. What you want is actually incredibly complex. Lexographic analysis is a bit beyond the scope of what you're coding at the moment.

Comment: I don't think that matters in his case. He just wants no numbers

Comment: Just try to parse the return as a Double and catch NumberFormatException.

Comment: You could throw an exception after checking if an input is a number.

Comment: If exception is caught then they didn't enter a number.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you wanna use Try/Catch method?

I mean the code below should do anything with your request:

```
Object helloworld = "";

if( helloworld instanceof String ) {
  // do something String related to helloworld
}
```

Ofcourse, if you insists on try/catch.

Try put:

```
catch (Exception ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with the regex `\\D+` which will not match digits.

```
String strFail = "cc1";
String strPass = "abc";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\D+");
System.out.println(strFail + ": " + p.matcher(strFail).matches());
System.out.println(strPass + ": " + p.matcher(strPass).matches());
```

Output is

```
cc1: false
abc: true
```

Comment: What does `\\D+` mean?

Comment: `\\d` means a digit. `\\D` means **not** a digit. A digit in this case, is a character `0`-`9`. The `+` means one and more. So, match everything not a digit. Also, this question is almost eight years old.